# RMS Radius of N-Body Simulation

Tags: python, simulation, physics

I am trying to simulate a globular cluster and investigating the root-mean-square radius of the system as it evolves. I want to ignore particles which are "lost" from the system.

However when trying to calculate the rms radius of the system, I have come up with 2 approaches.

1. Ignore all particles outside of a given radius. – The problem I have with this is that the system moves as a whole in a certain direction so eventually no particles are included in the calculation.
2. Ignoring particles with a velocity > escape velocity of the system. – I have the issue here of some partiles being flung out very far yet still being gravitationally bound to the system and returning dominating the rms calculation.

As shown in the gif attached the body moves down as a whole. Is there a way I would be able to find the centre of mass of just this system rather than the system as a whole (black dot) which I could then use to exclude particles outside of a given radius from the CoM of this body.

The body does only move in the z direction so I could potentially ignore particles with an x or y magnitude greater than a certain value, but then have the issue of this not always being the same when I later change the configuration of the system (e.g particles of different mass/differnt starting positions

[image: Gif of system]).

Comment: I think you can use a clustering algoritm to find which points belong to the group of points you are interested in. Then you could calculate the RMS value of those points.

Comment: When you assign the masses of all N bodies and their initial positions and velocities, you can freely choose the masses and the initial positions of N bodies, while selecting N-1 velocities for N-1 of the bodies freely. The velocity of the last body will be `v_N = - sum( m_i*v_i  :  i=1:N-1) / m_N`. This guarantees that the center of gravity of the system stays put.